# Multi replace values according to template

Tags: r

In order to make a GROUP VARIABLE for long data, I want to group multiple values into one new value.

I have already one solution but I feel there could be a better implementation.

```
set.seed(1337)
df <- data.frame(coli = sample(rep(1:6,2)), newi = 0 )

replaceList <- list(oneAndTwo=1:2, threeAndFour=3:4, fiveAndSix=5:6)
```

#### Data looks like:

```
> df
   coli newi
1     1    0
2     6    0
3     1    0
4     5    0
5     3    0
6     2    0
7     6    0
8     2    0
9     4    0
10    4    0
11    3    0
12    5    0
```

#### Lookup template looks like:

```
> replaceList
$oneAndTwo
[1] 1 2

$threeAndFour
[1] 3 4

$fiveAndSix
[1] 5 6
```

#### Desired result:

```
   coli         newi
1     1    oneAndTwo
2     6   fiveAndSix
3     1    oneAndTwo
4     5   fiveAndSix
5     3 threeAndFour
6     2    oneAndTwo
7     6   fiveAndSix
8     2    oneAndTwo
9     4 threeAndFour
10    4 threeAndFour
11    3 threeAndFour
12    5   fiveAndSix
```

#### My working try

```
mapply(function(fnd,rplc){IND=df$coli %in% fnd;df$newi[IND]<<-rplc},fnd=replaceList,rplc=names(replaceList))
```

If there is a better practice, also in regards to how to set up the `replaceList` I'm happy to learn.

How would you tackle/approach such a problem?

Comment: Your data doesn't match with the seed. With 1337 seed, df$coli should be 1,6,1, ...

Comment: Thank you. Very attentive! I fixed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can `stack` the `list` to a key/value dataset ('df2') and then do a `match` between the 'coli' of 'df' with 'values' column of 'df2' to get the corresponding index for 'ind' and assign it to 'newi'

```
df2 <- stack(replaceList)
df$newi <- df2$ind[match(df$coli, df2$values)]
df
#   coli         newi
#1     4 threeAndFour
#2     3 threeAndFour
#3     6   fiveAndSix
#4     1    oneAndTwo
#5     2    oneAndTwo
#6     1    oneAndTwo
#7     5   fiveAndSix
#8     2    oneAndTwo
#9     4 threeAndFour
#10    6   fiveAndSix
#11    3 threeAndFour
#12    5   fiveAndSix
```

Comment: Nice way. Already like that more than mine. Let's see what else is there!

Answer (score 3):

Make a named *vector* instead of your `replaceList` *list*, then match by name:

```
set.seed(1337);df <- data.frame(coli = sample(rep(1:6,2)), newi = 0 )

# make a named vector
myLookup <- setNames(c("oneAndTwo","oneAndTwo","threeAndFour","threeAndFour","fiveAndSix","fiveAndSix"),
                   1:6)

# then match by name
df$newi <- myLookup[ df$coli ]

# check
head(df)
#   coli         newi
# 1    1    oneAndTwo
# 2    6   fiveAndSix
# 3    1    oneAndTwo
# 4    5   fiveAndSix
# 5    3 threeAndFour
# 6    2    oneAndTwo
```

---

Other (**preferred**) option would be to use *cut*, and get *factor* column:

```
# using cut, no need for lookup
df$newiFactor <- cut(df$coli, c(0, 2, 4, 6))

# check
head(df[order(df$coli), ])
#    coli         newi newiFactor
# 1     1    oneAndTwo      (0,2]
# 3     1    oneAndTwo      (0,2]
# 6     2    oneAndTwo      (0,2]
# 8     2    oneAndTwo      (0,2]
# 5     3 threeAndFour      (2,4]
# 11    3 threeAndFour      (2,4]
```

**Note:** we could use `labels` option for `cut` and get your desired naming `"oneAndTwo", etc`. Again, in this case, I prefer to have numerical looking names: `"(0,2]", etc`.

Comment: You could make the lookup from the list itself `setNames(unlist(replaceList), rep(names(replaceList),lengths(replaceList)))`

Comment: @akrun Thanks, agree, but OP asking for "better practice", so I created the lookup var from scratch.